# React native can't access state when navigated from another screen from push notification

Tags: react-native, push-notification

I want to navigate and show popup when user interact with notification. I can handle if user intereact or clicks it and also can navigate to the page i want.

Then i'm tring to show popup with setstate but nothings happen.

This code works when user in Dashboard page

```
 componentDidMount() {


    PushNotification.configure({
      onNotification: function (notification) {
        if (notification) {
          if (notification.userInteraction && notification.data.data == "true") {
            NavigationService.navigate("Dashboard", {
              visib: true,
            });
            setTimeout(
              function () {
                t.setState({ ovrlayVisible: true }, () => {
                  t.getMeetDetail(notification.data.dataId);
                });
              }.bind(this),
              2000
            );
          }
        }
      },
      requestPermissions: true,
    });

}
```

I'm making it all in didmount. what should i do. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
   componentDidMount()
     {
    this._unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () =>
          {//your set state code. this function run every time when you navigate to dashboard screen});

     }


         componentWillUnmount() {
          this._unsubscribe();
          }
```

decrease settimeout time